# How to determin if iOS6 safari browser is in fullscreen or browser mode?

Tags: iphone, web, ios6

I'm developing web application in javascript/html5/css that have different layouts in fullscreen and browsermode. Is there any method to termin if user switches between fullscreen and browser mode on iOS6.

Comment: iOS 6 is still under NDA and according to the agreement of the Beta you are not allowed to talk about iOS 6 other then the Apple Developer Forum.

Comment: I'm no expert but I think you can achieve it by detecting screen resolution. Refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587499/detecting-browser-client-area-size-on-wide-screen-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
var isOpenFromHomeScreen = navigator.standalone; //true false
```

Answer (score 0):

you could build a function in php

something like:

```
$user_agent     =   $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

    function getBrowser() {
            global $user_agent;
            $browser        =   "Unknown Browser";
            $browser_array  =   array(
                                    '/msie/i'       =>  'Internet Explorer',    //Old version from IE
                                    '/Trident/i'    =>  'Internet Explorer',    //New version from IE
                                    '/firefox/i'    =>  'Firefox',
                                    '/safari/i'     =>  'Safari',
                                    '/chrome/i'     =>  'Chrome',
                                    '/opera/i'      =>  'Opera',
                                    '/netscape/i'   =>  'Netscape',
                                    '/maxthon/i'    =>  'Maxthon',
                                    '/konqueror/i'  =>  'Konqueror',
                                    '/mobile/i'     =>  'Handheld Browser'
                                );
            foreach ($browser_array as $regex => $value) { 
                if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
                    $browser    =   $value;
                }
            }
            return $browser;
        }
```

Then you could do what you want with it, like: `echo getBrowser();` or depending on the answer change the css.